# I have IConfiguration obtained from a CDT project, how do I keep a copy of it for use after deleting it from project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have obtained the Configuration (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.IConfiguration
) from the CDT project using:

```
IConfiguration[] c = ManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(project).getManagedProject().getConfigurations();
```

Now I want to keep a copy of this in my class and then delete it. After I delete it, I want to use the copy to obtain certain properties from that old configuration.

**Now I can't just do,**

```
IConfiguration cBackup = c;
```

Reason is that, it will be a reference to the old configuration and when deleted it will be lost. I know that I can create a dummy configuration using this configuration, but it will be added to the project [later while exiting class, the created config can be created] but I dont want to do this. So what are my options here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually created my own class to hold all needed information. Seemed like the only way out.